# java image processor on jenkins does not see the desktop

Tags: java, image, macos, jenkins, screenshot

On Mac, I'm trying to perform some image processing. When I run my code in the terminal, it works fine but it fails in Jenkins.
I created a jar file that captures screen for testing and the captured screen is black meaning that it does not see the desktop.

I have used xvnc jenkins plugin and enabled the default vnc.
and here is how I run the jar file:

```
java -jar -Djava.awt.headless=false -Xmx2048m test.jar
```

Inside the code I printed whether it is running headless or not. It is NOT headless.
but the Jenkins system information shows `java.awt.headless=true` and I was not able to change that.

Any ideas how to make this work on Jenkins?

**NOTE:** the screen capture is just for testing. The ultimate goal is to do image processing on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. You'd need 2 things to make it work:

- **xvnc** This plugin should be installed and setup properly
- **non-headless Jenkins**
  If you start Jenkins from a DemonLauncher (plist), you will not be able to access the desktop, so instead, start the Jenkins server from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins runs with its own user, usually, so it does not see the desktop you expect it to.

It is better to keep required files and other resources on shared folders.